# Lazy loading error in R package

Tags: r

I am building R package in R version 3.1.3, but whenever i try to install it I get the following error message;

```
* installing *source* package ‘SPO’ ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error : argument "data" is missing, with no default
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘SPO’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘SPO’
* removing ‘/home/evans/Desktop/SPO.Rcheck/SPO’
```

Kindly any help on how to fix lazy loading problem will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you running a function that has a missing argument `"data"` somewhere in the package?  Try running all examples, functions, demos,  etc. individually in the console of a fresh R session.

Comment: Thank you so much. I fixed the problem, it was about missing argument in one of my functions.

Comment: "ERROR: lazy loading failed for package" is just R stating that it encountered an error when trying to build the package; the underlying problems are the errors listed on the previous lines.

Answer (score 13):

This error message also occurs if you have uncommented code in the function file that is **outside** of the function definition.

The solution is to comment out, or delete, the code that is not inside your function.

Comment: Definitively the right thing to do for me. But a simple precision : the error occurs when you have written something outside the functions you've written in R  (any file in the R directory is concerned), not the C++ files...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I found an inactive/unused R file in the R folder of the package I wanted to build.

Once I deleted/removed this file, I was able to build the package.

Answer (score 2):

The error is usually caused by missing arguments (as stated in the comments) or packages.

For example, I had the following in my package:

```
library("DESeq2")
```

I couldn't build and install my package because the package DESeq2 was not installed. Once I installed the package, everything worked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you are not supposed to use `library()` in a package.  See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html#r-differences

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by madsR suggestion I have deleted **.RData** and **.Rhistory** files from the package folder. Then the error kindly disappeared.

Comment: Personally, I had a .txt file in the data subdirectory which was not documented. I erased the file and everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for installing package `gt`. The problem was that my `magrittr` should have been updated before loading `gt`. But trying to updating that also didn't work and adding True for dependencies and closing and re-opening of RStudio also not helped me.
So, I tried to **clear my environment** in RStudio because there seemed to be an error related to that, and then everything worked fine.