# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'aomisc'

Tags: r, quick-install-package

I am trying to install 'aomisc' from GitHub in R and I am getting this error:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/kyrad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'aomisc' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: (converted from warning) package 'drc' was built under R version 4.0.2
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'aomisc'
* removing 'C:/Users/kyrad/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/aomisc'
Error: Failed to install 'aomisc' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/kyrad/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0UXlX8/file8f9417e57d8b/aomisc_0.64.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Please help!
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered before.

Reference: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122780/lazy-loading-error-in-r-package)

The following 3 could be the answers:

> The error is usually caused by missing arguments (as stated in the comments) or packages. For example, I had the following in my package: library("DESeq2")
> I couldn't build and install my package because the package DESeq2 was not installed. Once I installed the package, everything worked.

Reference: [Answer - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33383444/11758843)

> This error message also occurs if you have uncommented code in the function file that is outside of the function definition. The solution is to comment out or delete, the code that is not inside your function.

Reference: [Answer - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38001019/11758843)

> In my case, I found an inactive/unused R file in the R folder of the package I wanted to build. Once I deleted/removed this file, I was able to build the package.

Reference: [Answer - 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181906/11758843)